# Bootstrap's input width 100% within form-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap inline form like dropdown-input-button. I was able to do this, but how can I make 100% width of input tag? Code snippet below.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xt4zk62v/

Comment: Please be more clear.  You are trying to make what 100% of input tag?

Comment: Sure, I want input field make wider. I have 3 elements, dropdown, button and input, so input width has to be 100% of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class and apply it to the parent div that adds a width to it and update the width on the input to 100%;

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.form-inline .form-control {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
} 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3xd3esq/4/